# Absolute positioned elements get messed up when zoomed in browser?

Tags: html, css, web-applications

I'm designing a clock using CSS and the design's proportions become awry whenever I zoom in. The proportions should stay the same whenever I zoom in. Does anyone know what part of my code is leading to the circles' proportions becoming askew?

Here is what [the clock looks like normally](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2vED1.png) and here is what it looks like [when I zoom in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2TnbB.png). Notice that the blue circle and the black dot are no longer centered.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

.section-clock {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #00a2ff;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 9.6rem 0;
}

.top-dot {
  height: 1.2rem;
  width: 1.2rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: black;
}

.middle-layer {
  height: 20rem;
  width: 20rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #59c3ff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: 10;
}

.last-layer {
  height: 30rem;
  width: 30rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1.2rem solid black;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35) 0px 5px 15px;
}
```

```html
<section class="section-clock">
  <div class="clock-container">
    <div class="middle-layer">
      <div class="top-dot"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="last-layer"></div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: I have edited your code to create a snippet. It seems that the code you have provided us does not reflect the problem you presented in the images. Could you provide [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and perhaps even [improve your question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

If you change `position: relative;` on `.last-layer` to

```
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
```

it is fixed